# How to interact with a specific website using scripts?

Tags: python-2.7, web

i want to interact ('interact' means 'submit my input and get the results from it') with https://uscensus.prod.3ceonline.com using scripts so that the process can be automated,rather than manually typing/click the 'classify'.
what is the best way to do it ? (preferably wanna do it in python) 
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There three main solutions that can be done in Python:

- [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium): which can automate browser behavior
- [mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/): which does not need a browser, allow for form submissions etc.
- going hardcore using [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) or [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) to make direct HTTP calls